# identify the frequency of the common pattern from a number of integers

Tags: r, pattern-matching, frequency, frequency-analysis, frequency-distribution

I have many rows of integers with 7 columns each, it is some biological points recorded from experiment. The numbers are from 1 to 7 only and I would like to identify the common pattern of those integers appeared.

```
first few rows of df:

        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
   [1,]    1    2    3    4    6    7    7
   [2,]    1    2    2    3    3    5    7
   [3,]    1    2    2    3    3    4    5
   [4,]    2    3    4    7    7    7    7
   [5,]    1    1    3    4    5    6    7
   [6,]    2    2    3    3    4    6    6
   [7,]    1    1    2    3    3    6    6
   [8,]    2    2    3    4    6    6    7
   ...
```

for instances,

```
desired output:

pattern freq
1 2 3 4 1
2 3 4 6 2
1 2 3   4
2 2 3   4
...
...
```

Please advice, thanks.

Comment: I removed the package recommendation. I mean the pattern is like the frequency of the numbers appeared together like number 1,2,3 they have been appeared together 4 times in the above rows.

Comment: if you had a row `2 2 2 2 2 2 2`, how many instances of `2 2 2` would that count as?

Comment: your example shows sequences of length 4, your comment suggests sequences of length 3 ...

Comment: so far I don't have this data, but in that case, i would count as 1

Comment: is it sequence of length 4 has less patterns and more easy to do find the frequency ? if so, i prefer length of 4 is better.

Comment: i think 1 is better

Answer (score 6):

```
dt = read.table(header = TRUE, 
text ="X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1    2    3    4    6    7    7
1    2    2    3    3    5    7
1    2    2    3    3    4    5
2    3    4    7    7    7    7
1    1    3    4    5    6    7

", stringsAsFactors= F)


# create a new column `x` with the columns collapsed together
dt$x <- apply( dt[ , names(dt) ] , 1 , paste , collapse = " ")

library(quanteda)
d = dfm_tfidf(dfm(dt$x,ngrams = 2:7, skip = 0:7), scheme_tf = "boolean", scheme_df="unary")
topfeatures(d, 25)
```

Answer (score 2):

For each sequence length we call `freqs` which for each row of `m` invokes `rollapply` to get successive subsequences.  `ag` contains each subsequence along with its frequency and finally we omit subsequencies not having a minimum frequency of `minFreq` to keep the size down.

In the last line of code we call `freqs` successively with values of `k` (the subsequence length) for 4, 3, 2 and 1 to get subsequences of those lengths.  Change 4:1 to whatever you want.  Also in that line omit `minFreq=2` if you want all the frequencies and not just those that are at least 2.  (We used at least 2 to keep the output size reasonable.)

```
library(plyr)
library(zoo)

freqs <- function(k, m, minFreq = 1) {
  tuples <- if (k == 1) matrix(m) 
    else do.call("rbind", lapply(split(m, row(m)), rollapply, k, c))
  ag <- aggregate(list(freq = 1:nrow(tuples)), as.data.frame(tuples), length)
  subset(ag, freq >= minFreq)
}

do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(4:1, freqs, m, minFreq = 2))
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 freq
1   1  2  2  3    2
2   2  2  3  3    3
3   2  3  3  4    2
4   2  3  4  6    2
5   3  4  6  6    2
6   1  2  2 NA    2
7   1  2  3 NA    2
8   2  2  3 NA    4
9   2  3  3 NA    4
10  2  3  4 NA    3
11  3  3  4 NA    2
12  3  4  5 NA    2
13  3  4  6 NA    3
14  4  6  6 NA    2
15  7  7  7 NA    2
16  1  1 NA NA    2
17  1  2 NA NA    4
18  2  2 NA NA    4
19  2  3 NA NA    7
20  3  3 NA NA    4
21  3  4 NA NA    6
22  4  5 NA NA    2
23  4  6 NA NA    3
24  6  6 NA NA    3
25  6  7 NA NA    3
26  7  7 NA NA    4
27  1 NA NA NA    7
28  2 NA NA NA   11
29  3 NA NA NA   12
30  4 NA NA NA    6
31  5 NA NA NA    3
32  6 NA NA NA    8
33  7 NA NA NA    9
```

### Note

In the question the input is called `df` suggesting it is a data frame but the display of it in the question shows that it is, in fact, a matrix.  For sake of reproducibility we use this matrix in our computations above:

```
m <- matrix(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
  2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 
  3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 
  6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L), 8)
```